# arcpy.SelectLayerByAttribute_management reference a field and a variable

Tags: python, arcmap

I have tried every which way but the right way. I can't seem to get the quotes in the right spot. I have a float field called speeds and I want to compare it to a float variable I am calling Min_Speeds.

```
#arcpy.SelectLayerByAttribute_management(Phase2+"_layer", "NEW_SELECTION", "\"Speeds\" = '{0}'".format(Min_Speeds))
#arcpy.SelectLayerByAttribute_management(Phase2+"_layer", "NEW_SELECTION", float('\Speeds\') >= " float(\Min_Speeds)\)"")
#arcpy.SelectLayerByAttribute_management(Phase2+"_layer", "NEW_SELECTION","float(\Speeds\ >= 4)"
arcpy.SelectLayerByAttribute_management(Phase2+"_layer", "NEW_SELECTION", "Speeds > "[Min_Speeds]")
```

Comment: `"{0} > {1}".format(arcpy.AddFieldDelimiters(Phase2+"_layer", "Speeds"), Min_Speeds)`

Comment: “Speeds = {0}”.format(Min_Speeds)

Comment: "Min_Speeds" is an *unconventional* name for a Python variable. I suggest you follow the [naming guidelines for the language](https://realpython.com/python-pep8/) to make your code more legible. There are a number of answered questions here already, so you should search on "select by attribute" to review examples of correct usage. Incorporating a program variable  in an expression requires formatting that content, for which the `str.format` function is uniquely qualified (string math is slow, inefficient, and illegible, so I must discourage that)

Comment: Are yiou receiving any error? Or it simply give you a 0 selection as result?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest you use the [AddFieldDelimiters](https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/analyze/arcpy-functions/addfielddelimiters.htm) function to build your where clause, as according to the data source you're using, the way you build your clause might differ.

Try using something unambiguous like:

```
Min_Speeds = 100.0
arcpy.SelectLayerByAttribute_management(Phase2+"_layer", "NEW_SELECTION", """{0} > {1}""".format(arcpy.AddFieldDelimiters(Phase2, "Speeds"),Min_Speeds))
```

Here I am just assuming `Phase2` is the data source of `Phase2_layer`. Change it according to its actual data source if different.